# Pandas DataFrame has no attribute 'is_monotonic_increasing'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have a .csv file that I read in as a Pandas DataFrame. I'm then trying to convert it to a dask dataframe, but this results in the error `'Index' object has no attribute 'is_monotonic_increasing'`. How can I correct this?

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = pd.read_csv('s3://my-bucket/data.csv')
df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=5)
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-7f9c61e8a470> in <module>
----> 1 df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=5)

~/anaconda3/envs/arsae-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/io.py in from_pandas(data, npartitions, chunksize, sort, name)
    189         return new_dd_object({(name, 0): data}, name, data, [None, None])
    190 
--> 191     if sort and not data.index.is_monotonic_increasing:
    192         data = data.sort_index(ascending=True)
    193     if sort:

~/anaconda3/envs/arsae-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py in __getattr__(self, key)
   2403         elif key in self._dt_attributes:
   2404             return getattr(self.dt, key)
-> 2405         raise AttributeError("'Index' object has no attribute %r" % key)
   2406 
   2407     def __dir__(self):

AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'is_monotonic_increasing'
```

Comment: When I re-read `df` using `pd.read_csv`, all of a sudden it now had the attribute `is_monotonic_increasing`.

Answer (score 1):

It raises the same when i try to create a dask `DataFrame` from another dask `DataFrame`.

What if you change the name of the dask DataFrame ?

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = pd.read_csv('s3://my-bucket/data.csv')
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that the `dd.from_pandas` is not attempting to create a Dask `DataFrame` using an existing Dask `DataFrame`. Initialise the Pandas `DataFrame` before reading:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

pd_df = pd.DataFrame()
pd_df = pd.read_csv('s3://my-bucket/data.csv')
```

Then use a different variable for the Dask `DataFrame`:

```
dsk_df = dd.from_pandas(pd_df, npartitions = 5)
```